# Matlab: Proper way to index vector; Error in Matrix dimension for index time series

Tags: matlab, vector, time-series

I am trying to implement this formula: [image: expression]

where y(t) is the output of an autoregressive process AR(2). t = 1,2,..,5000 data samples at equal intervals. p =2. The code throws the error

```
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

This happens because I don't know how to represent the lags in index notation which is stored in variable `L1`. Can somebody please help in mitigating this error by showing the proper way to index? This is how I have done:

```
var_eps = 1;
epsilon = sqrt(var_eps)*randn(5000,1); % Gaussian signal exciting the AR model
 Y(1) = 0.0;
    Y(2) = 0.0;
    for n= 3:5000
    Y(n)=  0.1950*Y(n-1) -0.9500*Y(n-2)+ epsilon(n); %AR(1) model
    end
p=2;
t= p+1;
rho0 = randn(); %c
phi1 = 0.1950; 
phi2 = -0.9500; 
L1 = (Y(t:end) - rho0 - phi1.*Y(2:end) - phi2.*Y(1:end)).^2;

L11 = sum(L1);
```

Comment: You need to make sure that all the terms in `L1` are the same size.  Hint: you can use terms like `end-1` in indexing.

Comment: If you define `t=(p+1):5000;`, you can replace your `L1`-line by: `L1 = (Y(t) - rho0 - phi1.*Y(t-1) - phi2.*Y(t-2)).^2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `Y(t:end)`, `Y(2:end)` and `Y(1:end)` are all of different lengths, so you can't add or subtract them. Probably easier to use a `for` loop:

```
L1 = 0;
for t=p+1:5000
    L1 = L1 + (Y(t) -rho0 - phi1*Y(t-1) - phi2*Y(t-2))^2;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am also interested to know if there is a rule for indexing. I have come across y(t) is written as y(2:end-1) ; y(t-1) = y(1:end-1) etc. I get confused when to put end-1 and which is the index to begin with.

Comment: `1:end-1` means "start at 1 and go to the last but one element of the vector in question in steps of one". Imagine `x` is a vector of length 5, then `x(1:end-1) = [x(1) x(2) x(3) x(4)]`. Personally, I'm not a big fan of vectorised notation and tend to favour `for` loops, where I deal with scalars only. I know it's not as efficient from a computational point of view, but I find the code more readable and understandable.